# Should I use "internal" or "domestic"?

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "internal" or "domestic"? And where? What word should be applied to internal/domestic market?

Comment: Both might apply, which market are you referring to?

Comment: Please given an example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Both adjectives may be used referring to a market. Both ***domestic and internal*** market are  generally used in contrast to   ***foreign*** market.

Example:

> - *domestic/internal market sales vs foreign markets sales*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internal%20market%2C%20domestic%20market%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinternal%20market%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdomestic%20market%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *domestic market* is a more common expression compared to *internal market.*